# How to write a protocol to pass data backwards to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

i was wondering how to write a protocol to pass data backwards to UITableViewController? If i write a normal protocol as one would write for UIViewController i get an error that "Type "TableViewController" does not conform to type protocol "PresentedViewControllerDelegate". "

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try using NSNotificatonObserver.

Comment: @BharatModi: that would be definitely the wrong way to go. Just overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your protocol, and have your custom UITableViewController subclass implement the protocol you created. Implement the required methods and properties in your controller and you're good to go.

Ex:

```
protocol YourProtocol
{
    func method1(par1: String, par2: Int)
}

class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController, YourProtocol
{
    //MARK:- YourProtocol Methods
    func method1(par1: String, par2: Int)
    {
        //Receive your data through this method
        //And Do your thing here
    }
}
```

Comment: "UITableViewController confirm to the protocol you created" how would one do that? D:

Comment: @Ekolu Simply makes your `UITableViewController` subclass implements the required methods of the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Only a protocol is not sufficient, you need also a `delegate`

- Declare your protocol:

  ```
  protocol PresentedViewControllerDelegate {
     func method1(data:[String:AnyObject])
     func method2(controller:PresentedViewController)
  }
  ```

  In the first method you pass a custom object (`Dictionary`),
  in the second method the destination controller itself.
- In the **destination view controller** `PresentedViewController` (the sender) create a delegate property:

  ```
  weak var delegate : PresentedViewControllerDelegate?
  ```

  and add code to call the methods

  ```
  delegate?.method1(someDictionary)

  delegate?.method2(self)
  ```

  The optional chaining is very convenient, the methods aren't called if the delegate is `nil`.
- In the **source view controller** (the receiver) add `PresentedViewControllerDelegate` to the declaration line, implement the required methods of the protocol and add a line in `prepareForSegue` to set the delegate.

  ```
  let destinationController = segue.destinationController as! PresentedViewController
  destinationController.delegate = self
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your TableViewController have not implemented functions declared in the PresentedViewControllerDelegate protocol. Implement those functions and you'll be fine.

```
protocol PresentedViewControllerDelegate {
  func somefunction(parameter: String)
  func anotherfunction()
}

class Table: UITableViewController, PresentedViewControllerDelegate {
  func somefunction(parameter: String) {

  }
  func anotherfunction() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right!